# What Icon Can Be Used to Represent "Attributes"?

Tags: icon, interface-design, symbolism, wayfinding

I am looking for a comprehensible icon/a visual metaphor to express "arbitrary attributes", in the sense of additional information.

In my particular case, each record represents a word, or a name, but the question is generally applicable for other cases - the additional attributes I am referring to provide some arbitrary additional information on the record; maybe it could be called "meta-information". To give an impression of what attributes I am talking about, here are some examples of that additional information are:

- Who created the record?
- How often is the record used?
- Is the record deprecated?
- In which century did the word/name stored in the record first occur?
- What other words (records) often appear in combination with this record?

etc.

So, to open the dialog box where the values of such attributes can be configured for a given record, I am looking for a commonly understood icon. My ideas so far, none of which I am completely happy with, are:

**Tools**

A set of tools is often used to convey "configuration", but that could be confused with the application-wide configuration that also exists in my program.

**Luggage tag**

A luggage tag could adequately convey the meaning of "attached information", but aside from said attributes, "markers" or "comments" can be attached to records, and I would like to use a *luggage tag* icon for those.

**Information *i***

Such a symbol would express that we are dealing with information about the record, which is ok, but it also implies that it is read-only information, a mere information output, rather than a way to *edit* said information.

**Is there any commonly understood visual way to express *attribute values*?**

Comment: (Can't comment.) Why not just `Edit...`, on a button? How much space is on the screen?

Comment: Little space: Primarily, a table is shown with, say, two or three columns (at least). In each *cell* (i.e. once per row row and column), there are at least two such buttons, one for the attributes, one for the aforementioned marker or comment feature, in addition to the actual text of the record.

Comment: Well maybe you can make it not a disaster to click on something and get into edit mode. If it's easy to get out of then what is the harm of pressing a row? It sounds like you are putting a picture on something that might not need a picture.

Comment: @Cakey: Clicking on a cell already opens up/focuses the editor for the cell contents. Of course, I could integrate the options to get to the attributes list there, but then the attributes could not be reached as directly any more.

Comment: @MrE.Upvoter: Sorry if my response offended you. As you can see in my score on StackOverflow, I do spend quite some time handing out *free* advice myself, so yes, I am aware of that. Answers so far have suggested several ideas, two of which I found most promising (Benteh's info *i* with a pencil, as well as Volker's plain list). For the others, rather than just saying "nay, no good", I strive to provide understandable reasons for *why* I decided against them - both so the answerers know I did think about their suggestions instead of just brushing it aside randomly, and so I can be made ...

Comment: ... aware in case I made a mistake and my objections are unreasonable. Referring to your specific suggestion, while reasonably appealing, it was *you* who pointed out that it represents "textual information" and implies being "old" or "dated", none of which I wanted to convey. Again, I apologize if any part of my question misled you to assume I was trying to represent specifically textual or old/dated information. Lastly, picking something apart and incrementally improving it is prone to lead to a high quality result, while just accepting the first thing that seems half-way reasonable is ...

Comment: ... not. I did not mean to say "try again", I wanted to express "Thank you for your effort, I see a few contradictions between my requirements and your suggestions and I will list them here both to get an overview myself and to give future readers a hint of possible thoughts about the suggestion." I will accept an answer and upvoted those that have helped in the solution of my problem, but as stated elsewhere, I will not do so immediately. I would like to get an overview and make my mind up about the options first, and besides, hasty actionism does not help anyone.

Comment: @MrE.Upvoter: I am wondering whether I should feel offended by your implication that software development does not require "real thought" or "original thought", though I do not suppose basing a grudge on that would be constructive. In any case, I can only upvote each answer once, which is exactly why I tend to wait for getting an overview first, so I can estimate what is "half decent", compared to the total sum of suggestions *and* the new ideas and thoughts provoked by the answers. Lastly, maybe it was easy to miss because I *started* my comment with it, but my first word was "Thanks".

Comment: And above, I meant "visually appealing" instead of "reasonably appealing". Unfortunately, the editing window has already expired.

Comment: @MrE.Upvoter: Technical answers have a solution that comes from previous knowledge and skills *combined with creative work to create a working solution that fulfils the requirements*. Often, there are many ways to solve the problem, none of which is clearly the *best* solution, and depending on their robustness and other contextual factors, it is sometimes not even clear whether or not a given answer is correct. I contend that my question here did contain all the required information. I indeed did not specify that I was not trying to specifically show "old" or "dated" "textual records", ...

Comment: ... but neither did I explicitly specify that my records do not contain any information on fish. Yet, an answer that suggests using a little fish icon to represent my records would not be a good answer to the question.

Comment: @MrE.Upvoter: I took great care to respond to each of your statements. I am sorry should I have skipped any of your sentences. Unfortunately, as you have chosen to delete both your answer and some of your comments, I cannot review your messages any more to comment on, as you said, your main point.

Comment: @MrE.Upvoter: As I explained above, I do give points, but rarely immediately so. And, no, records and attributes are not synonymous: Each record (which represents a word or a name) can have any number of additional attributes (which represent arbitrary additional information).

Comment: can you post some picture of you records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are after, are some way of indicating "more, unspecific information".

As @Cakey points out, not everything in the world needs an icon, so maybe some indication of editing might work fine.

**Luggage tags** are usually used for *tags* as in identifying synonyms on additional information, mainly as a help for search and batch. Such as `swiss` (cheese) would have tags as `cheese`, `milk product`, `europe`, `pasterurised` etc

**Tools** are configuration, so not really applicable.

You might want to think about:

three dots `…` (indicating more information)

an `i`, possibly with a pencil

The text "`(add) more`"

Another way - this depends on how this is set up: imagine a bar with a tiny arrow on it. Best example I can think of right now, is the bar here at GD: the "pull-down" text box in the answer-field:

[image]

This could be vertical of course. It would show there is more (and what is behind this "more" could be editable).

Comment: I prefer the suggestion with the info *i* combined with a pencil. Simple as it sounds as an idea, I think it most suitably conveys *editable* additional *information*. As there will be yet another type of "attached data/record-specific settings" beside the attributes, I think the three dots are too general. +1 for the extra hints about luggage tags referring to (single-word-)tags rather than extensive comments. I will think about that and at least make it clear that the comments can contain more than a single word.

Comment: It actually sounds to me that you might want to look at systems for museum collections - they do this sort of thing all the time.

Answer (score 1):

An icon representing generic control elements should work,
for example showing a two-part radio button.

Or, similar, a simplified equalizer control:

[image: icon example]

If a symbol of "control elements" causes confusion with a tools icon, representing just a list of items could solve that:

[image: list icon]

<sub>Images from [awoken-icon-theme](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=126344)</sub>

Comment: I fear this might get confused with the application-wide settings of the program itself, like the *tools* icon.

Comment: Good point - I try to find an example for the radio buttons - should be less confusing. Do you use a "gears" icon for tools?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I actually like the luggage tag most, but as you use it elsewhere - what about the plain list icon?

Comment: I'm probably going to use something like a gear + screw wrench to express the application-wide settings. I'm considering the list suggestion for the attributes (but as I'm not in a particular hurry, I'll wait some more days before accepting an answer).

Comment: +1 for the list suggestion, it is my second to favourite after the info *i* with a pencil.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try a small "graph" style icon to represent attributes:

[image]

I feel that this icon can't be confused with something such as "tools" or "options"

Answer (score 0):

An open or closed scroll (depending on how much detail you can include or how big the icon is) can represent "textual information", "archives", and "records".

Googled examples:

[image]

[image]

Adding a pencil would also introduce the 'edit' action.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately, I don't think these are suitable. "It represents 'textual information' and also implies 'old' or 'dated' 'records'." - Exactly, and neither is all of my information *textual* (How often is the record used? could be a number, for instance), nor are all of my records *old* or *dated*.

Answer (score -1):

Consider creating a prettier version of a scatterplot.

[image: Scatterplot]
<sub>(source: [ucla.edu](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/scatte1.gif))</sub>

Comment: Why? Can you explain your reasoning?